# How can I get data from azure web API in SPFx web part?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, azure, azure-ad

How can I load data from azure web API into SPFx web part?

API:

```
https://someazuresite.azurewebsites.net/api
```

Code I am using currently:

```
this.props.context.spHttpClient.get(`https://someazuresite.azurewebsites.net/api`,  
          SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)  
          .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {  
            response.json().then((responseJSON: any) => {  
              console.log(responseJSON);  
            });  
          });
```

Comment: Check [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aadhttpclient) and SPFx web part sample: [react-aad-webapi](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-aad-webapi) and [react-aad-implicitflow](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-aad-implicitflow). Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I tried but getting error of cors policy please see modified code

Comment: you have to use aadHttpClient and not spHttpClient. Check documentation and code properly and try to follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your web API is secured using Azure AD application, by using the AadHttpClient, you can easily connect to APIs secured by using Azure AD without having to implement the OAuth flow yourself.

Check this Microsoft official documentation for step by step tutorial for same: [Connect to Azure AD-secured APIs in SharePoint Framework solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aadhttpclient)

Also, check below SPFx samples developed and shared by community members which might help you with development of your SPFx web part:

1. [Call custom Web API secured with AAD from SharePoint Framework client-side web part](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-aad-webapi)
2. [Azure Active Directory implicit flow authentication samples](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-aad-implicitflow)

---

**Update**

Update from [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/306673/how-to-get-data-from-responsejson/306675#306675), use code like:

```
this.props.context.spHttpClient.get(`https://someazuresite.azurewebsites.net/api`,  
    SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)  
    .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {  
        return response.json().then((responseJSON: any) => { 
            for(let index = 0; index < responseJSON.length; index++){
                console.log(responseJSON[index].Title);
            }
        });  
    });
```