# how to get data from responseJSON

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts

I am trying below code but always get undefined in console for `console.log(responseJSON.Title);`

```
this.props.context.spHttpClient.get(`https://someazuresite.azurewebsites.net/api`,  
      SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)  
      .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {  
        return  response.json().then((responseJSON: any) => { 

          console.log(responseJSON.Title);  
        });  
      });
```

[[image]]

Comment: What is the output when you log `responseJSON`? Is it an object or array?

Comment: Is this API secured using Azure AD app?

Comment: its an array like [Title:"",id:""]

Comment: Array cannot be created like this. Simple array is like: `["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];` and array of objects is like: `[{Title:"Title 1",id:"1"}, {Title:"Title 2",id:"2"}]`. Can you add screenshot of response to your original question?

Comment: added screebshot and response is same as [{Title:"Title 1",id:"1"}, {Title:"Title 2",id:"2"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `responseJSON` is an array, you have to loop through array to get property values.

In place of `console.log(responseJSON.Title);`, you can use:

```
for (let index = 0; index < responseJSON.length; index++){
    console.log(responseJSON[index].Title);
}
```

You can find other ways like using `forEach`, `map` at:

1. [How to loop through an array containing objects and access their properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626735/how-to-loop-through-an-array-containing-objects-and-access-their-properties)
2. [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)